# tsconfig - How to set correct compiler output location for multiple directories (Atom)

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have this directory structure:

```
public/
    js/
        lib/
test/
    ts/
lib/
    ts/
```

How would I configure it to compile `lib/ts/*.ts` to `public/js/lib/*.js` and `test/ts/*.ts` to `public/js/*.js`?

I've tried setting up a separate tsconfig.json in each ts directory with the desired `outDir`, but as soon as I add a `///<reference` to a file, the compiler outputs an unwanted directory tree (on save and on build.)

Answer (score 28):

I ended up getting what I wanted with this layout:

```
public/
    js/
        lib/
        test/
src/
    ts/
        lib/
        test/
```

In src/ts/test/tsconfig.json:

```
"outDir": "../../../public/js"
```

In src/ts/lib/tsconfig.json:

```
"outDir": "../../../public/js/lib"
```

In src/ts/test/test.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/CoolStuff.ts" />
```

In Atom, if you're working in src/ts/lib, building will compile those files into public/js/lib.

If you're working in src/ts/test, the build will compile *.ts in test - *as well as all files referenced*. I don't see a way to prevent referenced file compilation, but at least with this layout they go to the same location.

Comment: Good solution. Will point to this in future if people want multi project folder structure guidance :)

Answer (score 6):

> How would I configure it to compile lib/ts/*.ts to public/js/lib/*.js and test/ts/*.ts to public/js/*.js?

If you want to compile `test` and `public` in a *single* compilation context then effectively your ts tree is :

```
test/
    ts/
lib/
    ts/
```

Therefore if you use an `outDir` of `./public/js` you will get:

```
public/
    js/
        test/
            ts/
        lib/
            ts/
```

This is because the *relative* nature of `lib/ts` to `test/ts` needs to be preserved by `outDir`. This is a limation in how you are trying to organize your project.

Reorganize your project as

```
ts/
    test/
    lib/
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I haven't found a good reference yet for how tsconfig and the outDir parameter works. Preserving relative reference paths makes sense now, I didn't understand why it was disobeying my direct orders in tsconfig.json. :)

Comment: Hmm, if I organize it like that and want to output public/js/test & public/js/lib, it generates public/js/ts/test & public/js/ts/lib. I don't really care if it compiles everything at once (compile file on save is fine.) Really I'd just like it to disregard the reference tag except to resolve dependencies, not to change the output folder structure.

Comment: Its in how the compiler is written. The commonroot logic is not in my control and I don't want to hack it in.

Comment: Ok haha, I think I figured it out. Using your layout, I can use 2 separate tsconfig files (I was trying with 1 global tsconfig at the root.) However 'test', which has a reference to files in 'lib' will auto-generate its own folder in the outDir. The tsconfig in 'lib' will compile files directly to outDir (unless I add reference paths to any of those files I guess.) I get why it does this (for requires and imports etc.) but I think the default behaviour should be "do as tsconfig says" rather than doing fancy restructuring based on reference paths.

Comment: basarat, thanks for all your help again it is much appreciated. I'm complaining about the tsconfig spec, not atom-typescript. :)

Comment: `do as tsconfig says` if we did just that then the files in your `reference` that are not in your `tsconfig` would get ignored and you would get compile errors

Comment: Sure, the reference path is used at compile time to find the referenced ts source, but I don't see why it must structure the output js like that. (For require & imports yes, but not for save, compile & reload browser workflow.)

Comment: I suppose part of the problem is that the compiler will compile and output referenced files rather than just using them to compile your file. The thing is I'm already doing that when working in the other directory.