# angular2 seed Typescript transpile settings (output)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-seed, transpiler

I've started using the Angular2 Seed by mgechev and i've a simple question regarding the Typescript transpiler.

Currently everything in the 'src' folder will be transpiled into the 'dist' folder. But at the same time all the .ts files are also transpiled in their own folder into .js and .js.map, which makes the whole folder a bit messy.

My question: How can I disable this behavior? I want the .ts files transpiled only once into the dist folder. Below my current settings in tsconfig.json

Thanks a lot and Cheers!

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/**"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908200/tsconfig-how-to-set-correct-compiler-output-location-for-multiple-directories) question to change the output directory for compiled files.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the outDir property into your tsconfig.json file with the dist value:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "dist" // <-------
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser/**"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```